# Library not found for -lOAuthConsumer_iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I have an iphone app to upload to the AppStore and I am stuck with Xcode.

It keeps telling me when I want to create a build:

Library not found for -lOAuthConsumer_iPhone

I have checked everywhere on the web and haven't really found what the problem is. 
Please bear in mind that I am not an iphone developer. I just know how to submit the apps but this bug here is really annoying as I can't find what it is.

Where can I find that library and how can I install it? 
And where to install it??

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the project is asking for the OAuthConsumer Library which can be found at: https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer.

You first need to check if your Project actually needs the library and ensure that the Security.framework is included as described in the OAuthConsumer readme

Comment: If you think an answer was useful, you can upvote it and mark it as accepted if it satisfactorily answers the question

Comment: Thanks for the reply:
I have downloaded it.

Now when I open readme I have this:

Comment: /Users/box/Desktop/jdg-oauthconsumer-b6fa84a/README: line 1: This: command not found
/Users/box/Desktop/jdg-oauthconsumer-b6fa84a/README: line 2: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c/OAuthConsumer/: No such file or directory
/Users/box/Desktop/jdg-oauthconsumer-b6fa84a/README: line 4: iPhone ready: command not found
/Users/box/Desktop/jdg-oauthconsumer-b6fa84a/README: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/Users/box/Desktop/jdg-oauthconsumer-b6fa84a/README: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You may be adding the README file to the project as a compilable file. It needs to be removed.

Comment: Ok, I am lost again... 
I have now the library, where do I copy it? How do I install it?

Comment: You'll need to import the files into the project and add the necessary frameworks and configs as described in the README. This may give a bit more insight: http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer

Comment: I have added the library but now I have this error showing:

Property 'pin' not found on object of type 'OAToken' 
On this part of the code: 
_accessToken.pin = pin;
_requestToken.pin = pin;